# How to optimize sql-handling executing through dbxmss.dll/sqlncli.dll?

Tags: delphi, oledb, dbexpress

A table defined on my MS SQL Server (2008R2) is defined as follows:

```
create table stagefm.dbo.article (id nvarchar(10));
```

I send a simple insert statement to my MS SQL Server through dbexpress (dbxmss.dll):

```
Q.SQL.Text:= 'INSERT into stagefm.dbo.article (id) values (':id')';
Q.Prepared:= true;
Q.ParamByName('id').AsString:= 'test';
Q.ExecSQL;
```

With SQL Profiler I see the following SQL executed on my server:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO stagefm.dbo.artikelstamm (id) values (@P1)', 
N'@P1 nvarchar(4000)',
N'test'
```

When I use a third party dbexpress driver (DevArt dbxsda40.dll) I can see the same behaviour when the driver is instructed to use the Native Client driver (vendorlib=sqlncli). I believe the standard Delphi driver also uses the native client (sqlncli10.dll).

Now when I instruct the DevArt driver to use sqloledb as the vendor lib, I can see the following with SQL Profiler:

```
exec sp_executesql N'INSERT INTO stagefm.dbo.artikelstamm (id) values (@P1)', 
N'@P1 nvarchar(10)',
N'test'
```

I would have expected this code for the native Client SQL  too, but the Native client seems to generate always nvarchar(4000) vars even for simple nvarchar(1) or char(3) fields.

Is it possible to optimize the SQL handling for Native client too ?

Comment: So, is the problem that SQL trace shows nvarchar(4000) ? If yes, then why it is the problem ?

Comment: @da-soft: yes, this is the problem as I guess that this slows down the performance. In real life I have to insert many rows (>500.000) with around 30 columns of nvarchar(n) where n<=50. This takes a long time - around 30 minutes on our machine.  Tests with the sqloledb approach seem to be faster and I guess this is because of the nvarchar(4000) "problem".

Comment: Try to call `Q.ParamByName('id').Size := 10` before calling `Q.Prepared := True`.

Comment: @da-soft: thanks for the hint but I already tried that without success.